# count values in a row based on criteria in a column excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So this problem I thought could be solved with a Countif - but that function requires a 'square' array to look at. I have a list of staff names(Column with 28 rows), and a calendar with a shift type (365 columns, 10 shift types). What I am trying to do is count the instances of each shift type in a row, but keeping the row dynamic based on the staff person name. So if Bob is row 5 it will count his "D" shifts, but if I later move him to row 7 it will stay with counting his shifts. 
So Staff names in Column A5:A28, Shift types in Range B5:ND28. The summary page will move around staff names from row to row so I need to be able to count shift types based on the name in Column A and match the row with that value. I am too much of a noob to embed images...

Comment: Where is your output formula? What does the current formula look like now? How are we supposed to know what shift type is supposed to be counted for each name? What about these rows with multiple shift types? There are some key pieces of your question missing here.

Comment: So for each staff name, you want to count the occurrences of each shift type ? Or does each staff member only do one particular shift ? And where is that information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image]

Column L contains the name you're looking for from your grid, column M contains the Shift Type you want to count for that name, cell N2 contains this formula to get the count and is copied down:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(B:J,MATCH(L2,A:A,0),0),"*"&M2&"*")
```

Comment: I was going to suggest D, N, and S be column headers, and names for row names and the count as the resulting intersect values, however just realized no indication of data layout was given for input or output...great job of assuming a scenario!

Comment: Many thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/2665425/tigeravatar! That was the formula I was looking for. Tweaked it slightly (didn't need the wildcards) and it works like a charm!